Roadmaps to become a blockchain engineer?
I know that this kind of sounds off topic but I just cannot find anywhere on the internet except the documentations.
How can one become a core blockchain engineer like implementing consensus mechanisms and all the other layers of a blockchain. All the roadmaps I’ve come across is about developing on the blockchain (such as Solidity courses, Hardhat and stuff)

It is true and unfortunate that there are not much material on the core layers.
here are some resources I've found to be useful:

Alchemy overviews on Ethereum
some videos of the Ethereum Engineering Group youtube channel
The Ethereum Yellow Paper
Reading the Geth node code and docs

it might be worth it to ask this question on the r/eth community too.
I wish you all the best through your journey.

Maybe this roadmap could be helpful
https://roadmap.sh/blockchain

Thank you but not really, this is the problem.
